# Powershell Import-csv with return character

Tags: powershell, import-csv

I tried the following to turn a text file into a document by leveraging import-csv where each item in the original document was a new line

Sample file.txt

```
James Cameron
Kirk Cobain
Linda Johnson
```

Code:

```
$array = import-csv file.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim `r

foreach ($Data in $array)
 {
    if (sls $Data Master.txt -quiet)
    {Add-Content file.txt $Data}
 }
```

It never created the document

Comment: "*It never created the document*". Dun dun dunnnnn. Too spooky. Did the villagers ever find James T. Kirk Cobain's HEADer?

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` takes a CSV and outputs `PSCustomObject`s. It's intended for when the file has a header row, and it reads that as the properties of the objects. e.g.

```
FirstName,LastName
James,Cameron
Kirk,Cobain

# ->

@{FirstName='James';LastName='Cameron'}
@{FirstName='Kirk';LastName='Cobain'}
etc.
```

If your file has no header row, it will take the first row and then ruin everything else afterwards. You need to provide the `-Header 'h1','h2',...` parameter to fix that. So you could use `-Header Name`, but your data only has one property, so there's not much benefit.

`ConvertFrom-Csv` is intended to do the same thing, but from CSV data in a variable instead of a file. They don't chain together usefully. It will try, but what you end up with is...

A single object, with a property called `'@{James=Kirk}'` and a value of `'@{James=Linda}'`, where 'James' was taken from line 1 as a column header, and the weird syntax is from forcing those objects through a second conversion.

It's not at all clear why you are reading in from `file.txt` and adding to `file.txt`. But since you don't have a CSV, there's no benefit from using the CSV cmdlets.

```
$lines = Get-Content file.txt
$master = Get-Content master.txt

foreach ($line in $lines)
{
    if ($master -contains $line)
    {
        Add-Content file2.txt $line
    }
}
```

or just

```
gc file.txt |? { sls $_ master.txt -quiet } | set-content file2.txt
```

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- `gc` is an alias for [`Get-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=204574) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- `?` is an alias for [`Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)
- `sls` is an alias for [`Select-String`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- [`Set-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)